# Troubles with APDS-9900 proximity

Tags: proximity

So I've received few APDS-9900 sensors and found out, there's no library for it (9960 type is supported only). I took that library and device documentation, and created similar library.

Ambient light detection (without interrupts) works well, but there's trouble with proximity detection:

The "Auto-Increment protocol transaction" which should be initiated by writing (0xA0 | reg) to command register, does not work and returns two zeros instead of two bytes. See page 18 of the PDF docs (in repo).

0xE0 (Repeated Byte protocol transaction) returns at least second byte (seems so) of the ADC proximity integration result registers.

https://github.com/suculent/APDS9900_Ambient_Light_and_Proximity_Sensor

Comment: Do you have a 1.8v i2c bus? The function wireReadDataWord reads four bytes and the first two are ignored, why?

Comment: The APDS-9900 seems to have 1.8V I2C bus and I have it connected to 3.3V ESP8266. I don't have level-shifter, so I guess I could do that with some additional resistance. Single-byte transactions seems to work well.

As of the ignored bytes... first byte returns 0, second returns 10, attempt third returns 40 and the fourth seems to return mostly > 768, one of the ADC integration result registers (high or low, hard to tell, seems like low given the jitter...)

Comment: Is the function wireReadDataWord random code and you take two bytes and hope that those are the bytes that you need? Can you replace the contents of wireReadDataWord with two wireReadDataByte?

Comment: wireReadDataByte returns always zeroes from PDATAL and PDATAH registers. 

There's additional issue, where the proximity data is a 2-byte value, that is constantly updated using the ALS proximity integrator. The wireReadDataWord should solve this by explicitly requesting multi-byte transaction that should safely provide both bytes from the same integration cycle.

This does not happen with the luminance, which is also a 2-byte. I'm seriously thinking about ditching those APDU-9900 and replace with more expensive but more predictable APDU-9960.

Comment: I think that is a good choice, because of the 1.8v i2c interface. Perhaps something is damaged with 3.3v. You also need to fix the software issue when requesting two bytes. It seems that you have made a workaround in the function wireReadDataWord, but that workaround is wrong anyway. While waiting for a new sensor, you could check every return value of Wire.requestFrom to see if you got the same number of bytes that you requested.

Comment: The workarond by fetching 2-bytes twice is more a debugging work in progress. I've already checked the return values... I suppose the problem will be in 1.8V I2C which will fail on multi-byte transaction attempt.